# Extend CardView makes cardview's own attributes not functional at all

Tags: android, kotlin, android-view, android-xml, android-cardview

I was trying to extend CardView on Android by kotlin using the following code:

HotCommentView.kt

```kotlin
class HotCommentView @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null) : CardView(context, attrs) {

    private var binding: LayoutHotCommentBinding

    init {
        binding = LayoutHotCommentBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this, true)
    }
```

layout_hot_comment.xml

```xml
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#f6f6f6"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp">

<!-- Some widgets -->

</androix.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

After that I tried to use my HotCommentView in other layout file, and I found out that cardElevation, cardCornerRadius did not function at all. The custom card view still have elevation and did not have 5dp of corner radius.

```xml
<com.xxx.view.HotCommentView
            android:id="@+id/hot_comment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="13dp" />
```

What am I doing wrong with extend cardview?

Comment: The internal layout should have `<merge>` tags as the root, not another `<CardView>`. The default attribute settings you have there now should be handled in code, either directly or through a default `style` and `attr` setup.

Comment: I have tried to use the following code, however it does not seems to work wther I use merge tag or CardView tag. ```        context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, androidx.cardview.R.styleable.CardView).apply {
            radius = this.getDimension(androidx.cardview.R.styleable.CardView_cardCornerRadius, 0f)
            elevation = this.getDimension(androidx.cardview.R.styleable.CardView_cardElevation, 0f)
            setCardBackgroundColor(this.getColorStateList(androidx.cardview.R.styleable.CardView_cardBackgroundColor))
        }.recycle()```

Comment: No, not a `styleable`. You don't need to handle those XML attributes directly yourself. If those are meant to always have the same values, then using attributes is kinda pointless, 'cause you can just set the actual values in the constructor without having to mess with `obtainStyledAttributes()`. Otherwise, if you do want to be able to override your default values with attributes on the individual  `<HotCommentView>` tags, then you just need to define a single  `<attr>` and a default  `<style>` (unless you plan on adding your own custom attributes later).

Comment: Thank you for the excellent idea. One thing I found weried is that I called setCardBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN) and the card is still transparent. I have removed all app: attributes from xml

Comment: Changing to merge seems working, that you so much for answering